# local.ERROR: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: View [errors.500] not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade

I have problem with laravel view is not found by route function. this error continually added in my laravel.log file so my project size increase day by day. I have clear out all the cache,config,routes,view,optimaize but not fix this. please help me.

> [2023-03-25 06:28:43] local.ERROR: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: View [errors.500] not found. in /home/testproject/public_html/Test_project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/FileViewFinder.php:137

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Do you have that view in `resources/views/500.blade.php`?

Answer (score 0):

First delete vendor folder after run this command in terminal:

```bash
composer install
```